# ModuleNotFoundError for python flask app. Script works during import OR direct execution but never both

Tags: python

I've got a problem with imports I just can't seem to find the answer to. I am using python 3, and have all the correct libraries installed. My file structure looks something like this:

```
run.py
.flaskenv
requirements.txt
/app
| - __init__.py
| - bot.py
| - /strategies
    | - __init__.py
    | - strategy1.py
```

run.py looks something like this:

```py
from flask import Flask
from app.bot import test_func
...
```

bot.py looks something like this:

```py
import strategies as st

strategy = st.Strat1

...

def test_func():
    pass
```

/strategies/__init__.py looks like this:

```
from .strategy1 import Strat1
```

Where **Strat1** in **strategy1.py** is simply a class.

---

As it stands, when I run bot.py directly, it works perfectly fine.

The problem arises when I start my flask app, I then receive the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'strategies'
```

Okay... So I try changing the imports, I change bot.py to:

```py
from strategies import *

strategy = Strat1

...
```

Same issue.
I try one more time, imports now look like this:

```py
from .strategies import *

strategy = Strat1

...
```

Works perfectly fine now during 'flask run', hooray!...

Except, now, when I run the file directly, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .strategies import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I am at a loss... I can either run the file directly with success and then importing it doesn't work. Or I can import it just fine but no longer run it directly.

I have attempted the common fix of

```py
import sys
import os

SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(SCRIPT_DIR))
```

and every variation of that, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: My best bet would be not to use relative imports. Inside `bot.py`, use
`from app import strategies as st`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a bit of a combination of everything.

Ultimately, what I ended up doing was this:

In run.py, I included the path adding before any other imports

```py
import sys
import os
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(SCRIPT_DIR))
```

In bot.py, I changed my import based on the comment from **evanstjabadi** :

```py
from app import strategies as st
```

At this point, running/importing the script from flask works correctly.

To get the script working when running directly, I added this at the very top:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import os
    SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(SCRIPT_DIR))

from app import strategies as st
...
```

Not sure if it's the cleanest fix, but it's now working in both cases!